# How could update the old row's value when I alter table add column and set default value

Tags: postgresql

How could update the old row's value when I alter table add column default value

type smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

but old rows is still null, Why can't update to default value automatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue an update statement prior to the alter table statement in your transaction:

```
update table set col = 0 where col is null
```

Alter table won't update the data because it's not its job or responsibility; updating is update's job. (The only exception I'm aware is when you change a column's type, in which case you can toss in a using clause to transform the data as you need.)